# Java/Javascript/flash upload library with bandwidth limit feature

Tags: java, javascript, flash, file-upload, bandwidth-throttling

**Is there any such library (like plupload, uploadify...), that has the feature of bandwidth limitation?** So when uploading files you can lower the limit to 25% or 50% percent of the full upload bandwidth?

I'd like to provide this feature to users of my website. It would be especially useful e.g. in small companies where you share the upload bandwidth with colleagues - then if anyone uploads big files then the internet gets stuck for everyone.

(I'm also interested if this is possible at any lower application level, see [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8978622/684229).)

Comment: Typically this concern is handled at a lower level, by implementing Quality of Service settings in router equipment. This to ensure a protocol like VOIP is not negatively influenced by uploading or downloading files from the internet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upload bandwidth limitation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978622/upload-bandwidth-limitation)

Comment: @michielvoo, I tried to go this way also, but its pretty complicated and you need to have rights to access the router, and not every router is capable of that (or it is, but it doesn't work in practice). I think the voluntary give up of bandwidth made by user is a way to go.

Comment: @michielvoo, nope! It's not a duplicate, this asks about limitation specifically in the website app!